# How to parse same name tag in Android XML?

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

How can I parse the same name tag in XML?

Here's a segment of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<item>  
    <RecipeDescription>A much requested chicken recipe! Easy to double for a large group. Delicious</RecipeDescription>

    <RecipeIngredientsName>1 tablespoon cornstarch</RecipeIngredientsName>
    <RecipeIngredientsName>1 tablespoon cold water</RecipeIngredientsName>
    <RecipeIngredientsName>1/2 cup white sugar</RecipeIngredientsName>
</item>
```

My XML Parser Class:

```
private void ProcessXml(Document data) {
    if (data != null) {
        recipesItems =new ArrayList<>();
        Element root = data.getDocumentElement();
        Node channel = root.getChildNodes().item(1);
        NodeList items = channel.getChildNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
            Node cureentchild = items.item(i);

            if (cureentchild.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                RecipesItem item = new RecipesItem();
                NodeList itemchilds = cureentchild.getChildNodes();

                for (int j = 0; j < itemchilds.getLength(); j++) {
                    Node cureent = itemchilds.item(j);
                    if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("RecipeDescription")) {
                        item.setRecipeDescription(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }else if (cureent.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("RecipeIngredientsName")){
                        item.setRecipeIngredientsName(cureent.getTextContent());
                    }

                }
                recipesItems.add(item);
            }
        }
    }
}

public Document Getdata() {
    try {
        url = new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDoc = builder.parse(inputStream);
        return xmlDoc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

But the problem is with the same `RecipeIngredientsName` names in the item. How can I get these values?
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

If the content in the xml file is Static then you can use the following method:

File Location is : ***res/values/filename.xml***

The filename is arbitrary. The  element's **name** will be used as the resource ID.

**Example:**

XML file saved at *`res/values/strings.xml`*:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="planets_array">
        <item>Mercury</item>
        <item>Venus</item>
        <item>Earth</item>
        <item>Mars</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

This application code retrieves a string array:

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```